# Inno Setup error when installing to USB drive root: "You must enter a full path with drive letter"

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to know how to fix this kind of Error:

> You must enter a full path with drive letter; for example: C:\APP or a UNC path in the form: \server\share

This appears whenever I try to force the Inno Setup Compiler (5.5.5 u) to put my stuff into, let say `H:\` instead of `H:\New Folder`.

I need the compiler to customize my destination location to `H:\`.

Here is my sample program;

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={drive:F:}
AppendDefaultDirName=no

[Files]
Source: "File1.txt"; DestDir: "{code:GetExeLocation|{app}\My_Portable_App}"; \
  Flags: ignoreversion
```

```pascal
[Code]
var
  UsagePage: TInputOptionWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  { Create the pages }
  UsagePage := CreateInputOptionPage(wpWelcome,
    'Installation Type', 'Select Installation Option',
    'Where would you like to install this program',
    True, False);
  UsagePage.Add('Normal – PC Hard Disk Installation ');
  UsagePage.Add('Portable – USB Drive Installation');

  {Set Default – Normal Install}
  UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex := 0;
end;

var
  bIsPortable : Boolean;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  // If we have clicked the next button on our custom page.
  if (CurPageID = UsagePage.ID) then
  begin
    bIsPortable := not (UsagePage.SelectedValueIndex = 0);
  end;
  result := true; // need to return a value so next key has an impact
end;

function GetExeLocation (Param: String) : String;
begin
  if bIsPortable then
    result := Param
  else
    result := Param;
end;

function InstallType(sRequiredType:String):Boolean;
begin
  if sRequiredType = 'Portable' then
    result := bIsPortable
  else
    result := not bIsPortable;
end;
```

Explanation:

When I select "Normal – PC Hard Disk Installation", as my choice, all my installation files or folders should go to normal Path that is to `C:\My Program`, but when I select "Portable – USB Drive Installation" as my Entry, I would like to put all my installation files or folders directly into the USB Pen drive Root, that is in here `H:\`, where "H" is my USB Pen Drive letter which I have selected to put my stuff in. But my Program does not allow me to do so, instead it adds a New Folder by default to put my installation files or folders over there, that is to `H:\New Folder` which I do not need that at all!. And when I force to do what I want, it ends giving me an Error!

Please I need Your Help to fix this, and if this inno-setup can not do what I want, please point me another one, and I will be Thankful for that!

EDIT:

Let focus on the second choice that is "('portable – usb drive installation')" because that is my real target.

From the Source:  I made some changes so that to make it more clear.

I added my destination Directory, that is `{code:GetExeLocation|{app}\My_Portable_App}`. So what I want here is that, all my installation files or folders to be installed inside this directory, I mean `My_Portable_App`. And the path to my USB pen drive should be `H:\My_Portable_App`. So when this goes fine, I want to see only This Folder `My_Portable_App` in my USB pen drive that will contain all my stuffs in there!!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, that `H:\ ` is a mapped drive ? And what do you mean by that you are getting that error if you select `H:\..(here!)....` instead of `H:\New Folder` ? Could you be more specific (possibly with a specific example), please ?

Comment: Thanks TLama for your quick response! I have posted an Example so that you can pass through and if stil not some how clear to be answered, let me know please!

Comment: I will be waiting for your reply, TLama!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install directly into `h:\` then you should explicitly enter that into the location box. If you also want to stop the `My Program` being appended after using the browse dialog then you need to ensure that `AppendDefaultDirName` is set to no.

Also note that for file2, the `DestDir` will end up being set to `{app}/{app}` if `bIsPortable` is true which will most likely expand to an invalid path.

Your best option is to use a `{code:...}` function to create a single "default" path based on `bIsPortable` and then everything can just install into `{app}` from there.

Comment: Thanks Deanna for your nice reply!

Comment: I passed through your advice and I made some changes, also I tried to put my installation path manually but when I press Next Button,still an error occur. Please look on my small changes that I have made and you may find a way to help me!

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the validation too, where root was not valid in the `TInputDirWizardPage`.
As it turns out there is a simple Inno Setup option that changes this behavior:

```
AllowRootDirectory=yes
```

will allow the user to specify a drive root without error.
also see,

```
AllowUNCPath=yes/no
```

and

```
AllowNetworkDrive=yes/no
```

in the Inno help file for other validation modifiers that apply to the Select Destination Location Page.

Answer (score 0):

This setup file must be located on disc c:.
That's all.