# Inno Setup installer that only runs a set of embedded installers

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I'm creating an installer in Inno Setup that will only run a set of embedded installers. It does not install any files on its own.

When compiling the installer, I am receiving this error:

> You must enter a full path with drive letter; for example: C:\APP or a UNC path such as \server\share

Below is my code but I have swapped out company info for test info. I have our full UNC path so I am not sure why I am getting this error? During this process, how are the credentials for the location being inputted?

```
[Setup]
AppName=DRsetup
AppVerName=DRsetup
DefaultDirName=C:\
OutputDir=.
OutputBaseFilename=DRsetup
DisableDirPage=yes
DisableFinishedPage=yes
Uninstallable=no

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[TASKS]
Name: MapDrives; "Description: Map the network drives"; \
    GroupDescription: "Application Selection:"; 
Flags: unchecked exclusive;
Name: Test; Description: "Test"; GroupDescription: "Application                         
selection:"; Flags: unchecked exclusive;
Name: Test2; Description: "Test2"; GroupDescription: "Application selection:"; \
    Flags: unchecked exclusive;
Name: Test3; Description: "Test3"; GroupDescription: "Application         
selection:"; Flags: unchecked exclusive;
Name: Test4; Description: "Test4"; GroupDescription: "Application selection:"; 
Flags: unchecked exclusive;
Name: Test5; Description: "Test5"; GroupDescription: "Application selection:"; \
    Flags: unchecked exclusive;
Name: Test6; Description: "Test6"; GroupDescription: "Application selection:"; 
Flags: unchecked exclusive;
Name: Test7; Description: "Test7"; GroupDescription: "Application selection:"; \
    Flags: unchecked exclusive

[Files]
Filename: {sys}\net.exe; \
     Parameters: "use I: \\Test\PUB /user:administrator /PERSISTENT:YES"; \
     Tasks: MapDrives;
Filename: {sys}\net.exe; \
    Parameters: "use H: \\Test\SYS /user:administrator /PERSISTENT:YES"; \
    Tasks: MapDrives;
Source: "\\Test\PUB\Install\Test.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: 
ignoreversion; Languages: english; Tasks: Test
Source: "\\Test\PUB\Install\Test2.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; 
Languages: english; Tasks: Test2;
Source: "\\Test\PUB\Install\Test3.msi"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags:         
ignoreversion; Languages: english; Tasks: Test3;
Source: "\\Test\PUB\Install\Test4.msi"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: 
ignoreversion; Languages: english; Tasks: Test4;
Source: "\\Test\PUB\Install\Test5.msi"; DestDir: "        
{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Languages: english; Tasks: Test5;
Source: "\\Test\PUB\Install\Test6.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: 
ignoreversion; Languages: english; Tasks: Test6;
Source: "\\Test\PUB\Install\Test7.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion;         
Languages: english; Tasks: Test7;

[RUN]
Filename: {sys}\net.exe; \
     Parameters: "use I: \\Test\PUB /user:administrator /PERSISTENT:YES"; \    
     Tasks: MapDrive;
Filename: {sys}\net.exe; \
    Parameters: "use H: \\Test\SYS /user:administrator /PERSISTENT:YES"; \
    Tasks: MapDrive;
Filename: "{userdesktop}\Test.exe"; Flags: runascurrentuser; Tasks: Test;
Filename: "{userdesktop}\Test2.exe"; Flags: runascurrentuser; Tasks: Test2;
Filename: "{userdesktop}\Test3.msi"; Flags:  
runascurrentuser; Tasks: Test3;
Filename: "{userdesktop}\Test4.msi"; Flags: runascurrentuser; Tasks: Test4;
Filename: "{userdesktop}\Test5.msi"; Flags: runascurrentuser; Tasks: Test5;
Filename: "{userdesktop}\Test6.exe"; Flags: runascurrentuser; Tasks: Test6;
Filename: "{userdesktop}\Test7.exe"; Flags: runascurrentuser; Tasks: Test7;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with any network location. It is referring to `C:\` in `DefaultDirName`.

For a general discussion about this error message, see:
[Inno Setup error when installing to USB drive root: "You must enter a full path with drive letter"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26687212/850848)

Though you do not install to USB drive root. You are trying to install to `C:` drive root. That's just wrong. You should never try to install anything to the `C:` root.

I understand that your installer actually does not install any real files on its own. Then, you should set both [`CreateAppDir`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_createappdir) and [`Uninstallable`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstallable) to `no`:

```
[Setup]
CreateAppDir=no
Uninstallable=no
```

And you should extract your sub-installers to [`{tmp}`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=tmp), not to `{app}`.

See also [Use Inno Setup UI as a self-extractor only - No installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51814408/850848).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate all of your help!